# Poor sound quality from the headphone jack

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, audio-jack

I am on ubuntu-14.04. The headphone port was working fine before but since a few days its behaving abnormally. But when I test the sound settings of my headphone drivers the test voice is crystal clear. But when I play videos on youtube or from my own PC I can hear voice but its a total blur.

Is this the problem of the software or the hardware? How do I resolve this?